# How to handle a pop up which is a simple HTML pop up in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to handle a pop up which is a simple HTML pop up in selenium webdriver . Its a pop up written in HTML .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the pop up is modal you have to do what the previous answer is proposing, but in case the pop up is just HTML you should just find a WebElement inside the popup code and work as usual, look the example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(popupid))
```

Pay attention and manage the implicit timeout in order to make sure the find will wait until the popup starts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use below given sample code and it will work.

```
public String parentWindowHandler = null,subWindowHandler=null;
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);//select new popup
    }


    /*
    your code here for script

    */

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);//return to main window
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find unique DOM properties because of sometimes same element properties like id and class same for HTML pop-up and parent Page.

So If it's unique then u can perform simply drive.findelements(By).click() , or sendkeys(), etc else u should be made unique XPath or by indexing, u have to click or perform other action.

SwitchTo uses if it is in iframe else it will not use.